# How to replace a space with backslash and space "\ " so bash shell script can read the file name from a .tsv file and perform rsync copy

Tags: bash, shell, csv, sed

I have a script which takes source and destination information from a tsv file separated by space. The first column indicates source file path, and second column is destination. My rsync command reads source and destination information and performs copy operation.

But the issue is source and destination files both contain filename with white space (header-background copy.jpg) and as we know that when bash shell reads a file name (with space), it replace the space with backslash followed by space “\ ”

`/data-prod/bigdata/abc/test/1143-1003-004_1143-1003-905/static/common/images/header-background copy.jpg   /mapped-data/data20/data3/header-background copy.jpg`

My question is how I can replace the space with “\ ” so shell can read it. I tried with using below sed command

`sed -r 's/^\s+//;s/\s+/\\ /g' test2.tsv`

but there is a problem as above sed command also adds a backslash after the source path. As I have mentioned that my script takes source and destination information from the .tsv file so having a slash added is a problem here. Below is the output of the sed command.

`/data-prod/bigdata/abc/test/1143-1003-004_1143-1003-905/static/common/images/header-background\ copy.jpg\ /mapped-data/data20/data3/header-background\ copy.jpg`

what I want is something like covert from

`/data-prod/bigdata/abc/test/1143-1003-004_1143-1003-905/static/common/images/header-background copy.jpg   /mapped-data/data20/data3/header-background copy.jpg`

to

`/data-prod/bigdata/abc/test/1143-1003-004_1143-1003-905/static/common/images/header-background\ copy.jpg   /mapped-data/data20/data3/header-background\ copy.jpg`

Comment: `and as we know that when bash shell reads a file name (with space), it replace the space with backslash followed by space “\ ”` No, it does not work that way. `like covert from` Are you _sure_ you want to only convert the string? Why not run rsync instead? Passing a string with `\ ` will still split on spaces, \ is irrelevant. Try it: `a='abc\ def' ; printf "%s\n" $a` `a tsv file separated by space` So it is a TSV file, so fields are separated by tabs? If so, split the string on tab and use two varaibles.

Comment: @KamilCuk explicit escaping of a string may be needed, like in `scp file.txt user@server:'path\ with\ space/'`

Comment: The standard escaping mechanism for TSV files is to use quotes. Backslashes have no special significance in regular TSV files. If you want to use a standard format, probably adhere to its conventions, rather than hacking in your own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `sed`, one way would be to group the match and return it with a back reference appending the back slash

```
sed 's/\([A-Za-z0-9\/][^\.]*\) /\1\\ /g' input_file
/data-prod/bigdata/abc/test/1143-1003-004_1143-1003-905/static/common/images/header-background\ copy.jpg   /mapped-data/data20/data3/header-background\ copy.jpg
```

Comment: Thank you very much HatLess! This is exactly what I was looking for (solution with a stream editor).

Comment: @mht.haque This solution have its limitations: only one space per path, and the filenames must have an extension. It may be enough for your needs though

Comment: @Fravadona I realized that too. This sed workaround worked with my rsync use case but didn't work with aws s3. As aws s3 cp command needed those paths to be double quoted. Before double quoting those paths in the tsv file, it was giving me <Unknown oprion:> error.

Answer (score 2):

> tsv file separated by space

At least use a `tab`, because a `tab` is less likely to appear in a path than a `space`.

***Remark**: Did you know that **only** `/` and `\0` (NULL byte) are forbidden characters for filenames in Linux filesystems? That means that everything but `\0` can appear in a path...*

Let's say that your file is now `tab` delimited and that your paths don't include `newlines` nor `tabs`. Here's how you can read it in BASH:

```sh
while IFS=$'\t' read -r filepath1 filepath2
do
    declare -p filepath1 filepath2
done <<< "/data-prod/bigdata/abc/test/1143-1003-004_1143-1003-905/static/common/images/header-background copy.jpg"$'\t'"/mapped-data/data20/data3/header-background copy.jpg"
```

Output:

```sh
declare -- filepath1="/data-prod/bigdata/abc/test/1143-1003-004_1143-1003-905/static/common/images/header-background copy.jpg"
declare -- filepath2="/mapped-data/data20/data3/header-background copy.jpg"
```

If you need to explicitly **escape** a variable (for example in the remote part of a `scp` or `rsync`) then you can use `printf '%q'` like this:

```sh
rsync -av "$filepath1" user@server:"$(printf '%q' "$filepath2")"
```

Answer (score 0):

Split the columns with parameter substitution:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    # count raw tabs to validate format
    tabs=${line//[!$'\t']}
    tabs=${#tabs}

    if ((tabs!=1)); then
        echo "${line//$'\t'/TAB}: less or more than one raw tab, skipping…" >&2
    else
        # split by tab
        source=${line%$'\t'*}
        target=${line#*$'\t'}

        rsync "$source" "$target"
    fi

done < list.tsv
```

The loop checks that each line has exactly one tab, and skips it if it doesn’t. Add in your `rsync` options etc.

Make sure the list doesn’t have symbolic escape characters (like `\t` or `\n`), or any other escapes/quotes that aren’t part of a literal file name. `tsv` and `csv` can have all sorts of different non-literal quoting, that needs to be parsed correctly.

Also note this usage of `rsync`, for copying files names from a list file to a single target: `rsync [opts] —files-from="my-source-list" /my/target/`